# How to create marker using imported JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the following code to import coordinates data(nested in initialize()):

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'http://.../stations.json', true);
xhr.onload = function() {
    loadstations(this.responseText)
    }  
};
xhr.send();
```

the function is like this:

```
function loadstations(places) {
    var temp = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    for (i = 0; i < 470 ; i++) {
        stations[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(temp[i+2].Latitude,temp[i+2].Longitude);
    }
}
```

But when I alert the stations data in the initialize(), it says 'undefined'. Thus, I'm not 
able to create markers using these coordinates.
Can anyone explain how these things work? I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap in anonymous function creating an instance of the class

```
function loadstations(places) {
    var temp = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
        (function(i){
           stations[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(temp[i+2].Latitude,temp[i+2].Longitude);
        })(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: I succeeded in loading the data, but how can I create marker on these coordinates? Where should I put the code?

Comment: You should place a markers creation just after stations[i] = ... ;

Answer (score 0):

The XmlHttpRequest is asynchronous. You need to use the data in the callback function when it is available:  You don't provide your initialize function, but this should add (default) markers at the LatLng positions returned in your AJAX request (assuming that code works).

```
var markers = [];
function loadstations(places) {
  var temp = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
  for (i = 0; i < 470 ; i++) {
    stations[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(temp[i+2].Latitude,temp[i+2].Longitude);
    markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({position:stations[i], map:map});
  }
}
```

Comment: how to write my call back function??

Comment: the callback is `xhr.onload` which runs when the data comes back from the server.